# iTunes Customer Reviews RSS Feed requests limit

Tags: rss, app-store, itunes, review

I was trying to fetch reviews for certain app in iTunes and after some count of requests I started to get `403` response code. I assume that there is some limitation depending on requests count for certain period. If so, does anyone know exact answer? How much time should pass since I'll be able to requests for reviews again?
I have 15 apps and fetching reviews for all countries. I requested JSON format. Is there the same limitation for xml?

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue. I am parsing rss in `JSON` format for my *n* applications for different counties. It's approximately 100-150 requests. And almost all request return `403` error code, but sometimes it's work ok and return json.

So, to solve this problem I migrate from `json` to `xml`. Here is my interpolated url (PHP):

```
$xml_url = "https://itunes.apple.com/{$countryCode}/rss/customerreviews/page={$i}/id={$appId}/sortBy=mostRecent/xml"
```